# Can I use enrollment token of ES which was generated in Linux server to kibana which is in windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have kibana installed in windows and elasticsearch in Linux server. In order to kibana work, enrollment token is needed. Can I use the enrollment token which was generated while starting the elasticsearch for the first time in linux server, or should I install elasticsearch in windows and get the enrollment token from that and paste it in kibana? Can anyone please help?

Comment: The enrolment token should not be platform sensitive.
Could you give us more information on what you tried ?

Comment: or what the issue you are seeing is if it's not working. cause it should work

Comment: Actually my doubt is whether can we use the enrollment token that got generated in one platform and use it to the kibana that is running in different platform?